# The usage of the apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe

Does the usage of the apostrophe in [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://amp.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2021/feb/16/always-sunny-glenn-howerton-ap-bio&ved=2ahUKEwjb4fLpvvXuAhULPOwKHZ_SBiYQFjAKegQIHhAC&usg=AOvVaw2R1tKKnp469n603r-mGfax&ampcf=1) article headline only occur in formal writing? Because I only see it being used in an article headline. I'm sorry if I'm talking nonsense.

> Always Sunny’s Glenn Howerton: ‘The characters can be horrible misogynists, we the writers are not’

- I'm talking about this structure: (thing)'s (person or  character) [complement].

Comment: It's a possessive form of "Always Sunny" as if the show owned the actor or the actor belonged to the show

Comment: It would look very strange without an apostrophe.

Comment: No, it occurs in informal writing such as newspapers. :) Newspaper headlines are not formal writing by any stretch of the imagination. *Always Sunny* is an abbreviation of the show "It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia" (I'm assuming). You have to factor that in when you read article headlines -- they are often abbreviated in strange ways to save space. Do not take them as indications of standard English.